# Term to differentiate between a flight and a flight instance?

Tags: terminology

What's a term to differentiate between a flight schedule (QF 72) and a particular instance of that flight schedule (QF 72 departing on July 25)?

For example, I might ask "Which flight are you taking", and you might reply "QF 72". What I really meant was "Which scheduled instance of QF 72 are you taking?"

The flight schedule and a specific instance of that flight schedule are both referred to as a "flight". What are the terms that more precisely differentiate between these two concepts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might say "the QF 72 *service* between Singapore and Perth" for the flight schedule, and "the QF 72 *flight* on July 25" for a particular instance of the flight.

The term *service* used in this way is seen more often in other transportation sectors such as bus and train. But it can also apply to scheduled air services.